# Show maintenace/repair/uninstall dialog when a user re-installs the same exact version of WiX

Tags: wix, wix3, customdialog

I am new to Wix. I am using WiX 3.10.
The problem is that when I install a new .msi that I made, everything runs fine. However, when I re-install the same exact version (nothing changed), it goes straight to the "Finish" Screen.

What we would like to do is tell the user that he/she has the version already installed, or make a maintenance/repair/uninstall dialog appear instead when executing the same exact installer on their computer.

I have been able to prevent downgrades using the MajorUpgrade element in WiX, I just need to be able to tell the user that the version of the software is already installed in their computer or make a maintenance/repair/uninstall dialog appear

currently all I have is :

Using this code, when i click to install the second time, the screen goes directly to the "Finish" screen.

I have not found any discussion like this on the Wix Forums here nor in the Wix Users QA site.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Regards

Jay

Comment: which UI are you using? Is it one from the WixUIExtension or an in-house UI?

Comment: Hi, we are using WixUI_Common.

Comment: sorry just realized that the code din't make it on to the quesiton post: i have

<MajorUpgrade Schedule="afterInstallInitialize"
                DowngradeErrorMessage="A later version of Eb Service Installer is already installed"
                AllowSameVersionUpgrades="yes" />
  <MediaTemplate EmbedCab="yes" />

Comment: Are you running the same exact build of the installer or are you rebuilding the installer and running it again without changing the version? If you are using product id="*" every build of your installer will be "different" than the others even if the version isn't changed.

Answer (score 0):

WixUI_Common comes with the repair/change/remove dialog, just put it after your verityReadydlg, adn the second time you install the same version, it will go to the maintenance dlg

1
        1
        1

Comment: <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RepairButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="RemoveButton" Event="NewDialog" Value="VerifyReadyDlg">1</Publish>
        <Publish Dialog="MaintenanceTypeDlg" Control="Back" Event="NewDialog" Value="MaintenanceWelcomeDlg">1</Publish>